# Sum of values from each previous li - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add up the values from each previous `li` and display the sum below the current `li` value

This is the html

```
<ul>
    <li>+2</li>
    <div id="sum" >Sum:</div>
    <li>+2</li>
    <div id="sum" >Sum:</div>
    <li>-1</li>
    <div id="sum" >Sum:</div>
    <li>-1</li>
    <div id="sum" >Sum:</div>                    
</ul>
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
+2 
sum: 2

+2 
sum: 4

-1 
sum: 3

-1
sum: 2
```

The values in each are generated dynamically. So What I'm looking for in jQuery is something like 'find the value in each previous li and give the sum of those here'.

Comment: html mark up is invalid `li` cant have `div` as sibling

Comment: Also it's bad to have multiple elements with the same Id, use class for that

Comment: Id be unique in html

Comment: Joelyorca, are you still having problem or?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - thanks so much for your help! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `div` inside the `li`

Try looping through each `li`

Then you can get the number in the `li` by "removing" the `div` like this `$(this).clone().find('div').remove().end().text().trim()`

```js
var count = 0;
$("ul li").each(function() {
  var number = $(this).clone().find('div').remove().end().text().trim();
  count += parseInt(number);
  $(this).find("div").text("sum: " + count)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>+2
    <div class="sum">Sum:</div>
  </li>
  <li>+2
    <div class="sum">Sum:</div>
  </li>
  <li>-1
    <div class="sum">Sum:</div>
  </li>
  <li>-1
    <div class="sum">Sum:</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ulChildren = $('ul >');
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ulChildren.length; i++) {
  var child = ulChildren[i];
  if (child.nodeName === 'LI') {
    result += parseInt(child.innerHTML);
    continue;
  }
  if (child.id === 'sum') {
    child.innerHTML += result;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li>+2</li>

  <div id="sum">Sum:</div>

  <li>+2</li>

  <div id="sum">Sum:</div>

  <li>-1</li>

  <div id="sum">Sum:</div>

  <li>-1</li>

  <div id="sum">Sum:</div>
</ul>
```